Show that $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $f(x)=x$ if $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is not continuous. Are my three proofs correct?
The task is to prove that the function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}x, & x\in\mathbb{Z}\\0, & \textrm{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
is not continuous.
I tried to write down three different proofs and I would like to ask whether each of them is correct.

Proof 1 (using $\varepsilon$-$\delta$-criterion):
Let $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ and $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$.
If $0<\delta<1$, choose $x=x_0+\frac{\delta}{2}$. Then, $\vert x-x_0\vert <\delta$ and $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert =\vert f(x_0)\vert=\vert x_0\vert>\varepsilon$.
If $\delta\geq 1$, choose $x=x_0+\frac{1}{2}$. Then, $\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta$ and $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert=\vert f(x_0)\vert=\vert x_0\vert>\varepsilon$.
Thus, there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that for each $\delta>0$ there exists some $x\in\mathbb{R}$ with $\vert x-x_0\vert<\delta$ and $\vert f(x)-f(x_0)\vert>\varepsilon$. But this means that $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$ and, consequently, not in $\mathbb{R}$.
Proof 2:
Let $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$. Then, for the limits from the left and right, respectively,
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)=0=\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x),
$$
meaning that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$ exists; however,
$$
\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0\neq x_0=f(x_0).
$$
Therefore, $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$ and thus not in $\mathbb{R}$.
Proof 3 (using the sequential criterion):
Let $x_0\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ und consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ defined by $x_n:=x_0+\frac{1}{n}$. For $n\geq 2$, we have $x_n\notin\mathbb{Z}$, and therefore $f(x_n)=0$ for $n\geq 2$. Moreover, $x_n\to x_0$ as $n\to\infty$. Consequently,
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=0\neq x_0=f(x_0)=f(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n).
$$
There sequential criterion is therefore not satisfied, i.e., $f$ is not continuous in $x_0$ and thus not in $\mathbb{R}$.
Please let me know if you see mistakes etc. Thanks!

Should I ask a question for each of my given proofs?

I’m voting to close this question because you asked for "solution-verification". Tag-description "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions. " Your question does not satisfy this requirement.

Hmm, ok. I just would like to know if the proofs which are very short, are ok. Was not aware of the fact that the way I asked causes problems.

Imagine someone tells you "I read the following proof in a book. Is it correct?" Wouldn't you ask this person "Which doubts do you have?"

I was just wondering whether the left- and right limits which I computed are indeed $0$. But since nobody complains, this semms to be correct. :-)
